# Actions Script 3.0 if else statements

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

need to do several things by it's click event. I'm a beginner to this, so is there any other way to write this code? by clicking this button, it goes to next frame and according to statement several buttons will be visible or not. I wrote the code this way and it says there are syntax error, but I couldn't find any. Hope you guys understand this and will help me. :) Thank you!

```
review_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, review1)
function review1(event:MouseEvent):void{

if(rvw1 == "Correct"){ 
    gotoAndStop(3627);
    help1.visible = false

    }
else{ 
    gotoAndStop(3627);
    help1.visible = true

}
}

review_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, review2)
function review2(event:MouseEvent):void{

if(rvw2 == "Correct"){ 
    gotoAndStop(3627);
    help2.visible = false

    }
else{ 
    gotoAndStop(3627);
    help2.visible = true

}
}

review_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, review3)
function review3(event:MouseEvent):void{

if(rvw3 == "Correct"){ 
    gotoAndStop(3627);
    help3.visible = false

    }
else{ 
    gotoAndStop(3627);
    help3.visible = true

}
}

review_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, review4)
function review4(event:MouseEvent):void{

if(rvw4 == "Correct"){ 
    gotoAndStop(3627);
    help4.visible = false

    }
else{ 
    gotoAndStop(3627);
    help4.visible = true

}
}

review_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, review5)
function review5(event:MouseEvent):void{

if(rvw5 == "Correct"){ 
    gotoAndStop(3627);
    help5.visible = false

    }
else{ 
    gotoAndStop(3627);
    help5.visible = true

}
}
```

Comment: You should at least examine if you typo'd some operator first. If not, or you can't see it, then add the error report to the question.

Comment: actually there are no compile errors, in output tab it shows syntax error...
Is there anyway to write this code simply???

Comment: If it writes a syntax error, it also writes a line where is the error. Check it and lines before and after it, if there is an unclosed or an extra closed bracket of any kind, etc. About code - yes, it can be simplified, given you are adding your listeners to a single button. The answer below has some simplification.

Comment: look at using " else if statements"

Answer (score 1):

I'll take an attempt at it. It looks like the only difference is that in each method you need to match up "helpX".visible with "rvwX" equals the string "Correct", where X is a number from 1-5. The gotoAndStop() frame is the same regardless. Also, that all five are meant to be off the same button. I'm going to take an assumption that the clips 'help' are movieclips defined on the stage else if they are from something else I would store them in an array for looping through instead of 'building' the name and finding the reference that way just for clarity.

```
function review(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for(var counter:int = 1; counter < 6; counter++){
        this["help" + counter].visible = (this["rvw" + counter] != "Correct");
    }
    this.gotoAndStop(3627);
}
review_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, review);
```

Comment: if the rvwX not equals to correct helpX's shouldn't be visible... and that doesn't do with your above code. :/ 
I'm a beginner to the code world and messing up with codes every time :p :D btw thanx for your co-operation. 
If you have time, could you please re-write the code considering below example. :D

if(rvwX == "Correct")
gotoAndStop(X);
helpX.visible = true
else
gotoAndStop(X);
helpX.visible = false 

Thank you very much for wasting your valuable time for me. :)

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. I had gotten the helpX's to be visible if the string is equal to "Correct" as you pointed out, when it should be the other way around. Edited my code to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do a class with 2 fields: "help" and "rvw" (let me call it "Switcher"). Also it may contain a function of setting visibility (may, not must, this function can also be in your main class):

Switcher.as:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Switcher {
    private var help:MovieClip;
    private var rvw:String;

    public function setVisibility() {
        help.visible = !(rvw == "Correct");
    }
}
```

Then you have to make an array of Switcher's objects in your main class and to use only one "review" handler:

```
function review(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for each(var sw:Switcher in switchersArray) {
        sw.setVisibility();
    }
    this.gotoAndStop(3627);
}
```

The code from previous answer will work correctly, but IMHO, creating an Array (or Vector) of similar objects is better than doing lots of help1, help2, help3 etc variables.